# openssl encypt/decrypt inconsistently working/failing

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, openssl, silex

I'm seeing some weird behaviour with the `openssl_*` methods in PHP. 50% of the time, it will fail, throwing `Unknown cipher algorithm`, and the other 50% of the time, it will correctly encode my data. Here's the relevant snippet from my code:

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$hash = openssl_encrypt($raw, "AES-128-CBC", $hashing_secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
// send $iv.$hash
```

using `openssl_get_cipher_methods` gives me:

```
[0] => AES-128-CBC
...
[81] => aes-128-cbc
```

so I know that the ciphers are available. Additionally, `$ openssl ciphers` lists AES-128-CBC as an available cipher at the system level (however, I've been told that PHP's bundled openssl is independent)

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, php5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14, openssl 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 (the version listed in phpinfo is the same). If it's relevant, all this code is running under the Silex framework via nginx/php-fpm.

**Update: A bit more info...**

I've done some more testing. I wrote a small script that just loops over x times, encoding some data.

```
set_error_handler(function() use (&$errorCount) {
    $errorCount++;
});

for ($i = 0; $i < $numTests; $i++) {
    $hash = openssl_encrypt($data, "AES-128-CBC", $hashing_secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);    
}
```

If I run that (via `php test.php`) on the same server, it runs consistently - i.e. `$errorCount == 0` every time. That leads me to believe it's either: a) silex or b) the fastcgi process that impeding the function - I've added those tags.

Not really sure where to go from here, now, though...

*Second Update*

I did a little more testing. I stuck the test script behind nginx, running php-fpm. The odd thing here is that either a) it fails 100% of the time or b) it fails 0 times, instead of a little bit of both results. This leads me to believe that it's nginx or php-fpm that's the culprit.

Comment: Are the key and IV **exactly the correct length**, key one of 128-bits, 192-bits or 256-bits and the iv 16-bytes?

Comment: You can see how long my IV is - it's exactly 16 bytes. And the key I'm using is 128bits (16 characters)

Comment: Do you check that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` does not return `FALSE`, From the docs: *Returns the generated string of bytes on success, or FALSE on failure.* Sometimes routines such as these do not have enough entropy to return the requested bytes. It might be worthwhile to add such a check and log any failures.

Comment: Also: is the same key used every time? The statement "(16 characters)" worries me, that means different things in different languages. Encryption works on 8-bit bytes while character many times refers to a particular character encoding such as UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. Personally I only believe a hexadecimal display immediatly prior to and after the encryption call of all inputs and outputs.

Comment: I had the key set to "abce..." 16 characters.

Comment: @zaph I added additional checks, `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)` doesn't return `FALSE`.

Comment: could check adding a sleep(5); in the for loop, and see if will still be failing 50% of the times?

Comment: I am seeing this same problem on NGINX with PHP7 on Ubuntu 16.04.2. Intermittently, I get a NULL result on a decrypt.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like it might be an OpenSSL mis-locking error. You should ensure that only one OpenSSL object is ever in use at any one time in the same process space.

To verify, run the test script so that it is the only one using OpenSSL. Does it still fail 50% of the time? Or is the failure only happening with multiple concurrent accesses to the script?

If it still happens, it almost has to be a bug in php-fpm -- it is instantiating the function and not clearing its data areas properly until an error occurs. In that case I expect it to fail once every two calls, not "50% on average" but exactly once every even-numbered call. In *that* case I'd try with a different version of OpenSSL.

To lock openssl, you might try using [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) and instantiate a lock file for use by the SSL function (first you check the lock is available, then run the function and unlock). Try this and see whether it works. If it does, you can look into a more efficient way of doing it - for example you might use a MySQL LOCK(), or a [semaphore](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) if it is available.

### Spelunking

The misbehaving function in 5.5.9 is to be found in `ext/openssl/openssl.c` and the error being thrown is one of the preliminary checks. No surprises yet:

```
/* {{{ proto string openssl_encrypt(string data, string method, string password [, long options=0 [, string $iv='']])
   Encrypts given data with given method and key, returns raw or base64 encoded string */
PHP_FUNCTION(openssl_encrypt)
{
    long options = 0;
    char *data, *method, *password, *iv = "";
    int data_len, method_len, password_len, iv_len = 0, max_iv_len;
    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher_type;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX cipher_ctx;
    int i=0, outlen, keylen;
    unsigned char *outbuf, *key;
    zend_bool free_iv;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sss|ls", &data, &data_len, &method, &method_len, &password, &password_len, &options, &iv, &iv_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    cipher_type = EVP_get_cipherbyname(method);
    if (!cipher_type) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Unknown cipher algorithm");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
```

So we can assume that `EVP_get_cipherbyname(method)` is returning a falsehood.

Except that it is a standard SSL function. I found this terse (and very possibly outdated) [reply](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=100939060430902&w=2) which seems to indicate there's some facepalm juice in the recipe somewhere. But this does not explain why the function should fail once every two.

The function is [here on github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6286757141a8c6e14d647ec733634ae0c83d9887/crypto/evp/names.c). It initializes OpenSSL, and it gets the method name via an [ancillary function](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6286757141a8c6e14d647ec733634ae0c83d9887/crypto/objects/o_names.c) that will return a pointer to non-nulled memory.

I had a farfetched hypothesis that the function was returning something akin to 0 or 81 at random (since both strings are in your cipherlist output, with indexes 0 and 81) and 0 was equaled to NULL, hence failing. It appears it can't work like that, and it should do so also in the CLI. **But just to be sure**, verify whether it is only that particular cipher that fails (while e.g. AES-256-CBC works).

The other possibility is that it's the `OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_ADD_ALL_CIPHERS, NULL)` call which is failing. This can happen if this test (on Ubuntu; other platforms behave differently) fails:

```
int CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once(CRYPTO_ONCE *once, void (*init)(void))
{
    if (pthread_once(once, init) != 0)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

This again would indicate some shared resource conflict deep inside libcrypto.

**As another test**, I suggest you do not call the random bytes IV initialization and try with a fixed IV; that's because I've also stumbled across [this note](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4165), which points to a slightly different resource than I was thinking of, but close enough to have me react:

> It appears that openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(), which calls openssl,
>   causes the underlying libcrypto to invoke a callback that was
>   established previously by PostgreSQL library as part of the lock
>   portability callbacks for multi-threading of openssl.
>
> Some information on the topic can be found here
>   http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Threads(3)

If HHVM openssl extension does not establish these same callbacks, it may be causing the wrong callbacks to be called.

The next tests I'm going to perform, time permitting, is to place alerts (in the form of static syslog calls) in the above mentioned failure points, to exactly pinpoint *which* test is failing... provided I can install the same setup as you have on a VM, and I can reproduce the same weird behaviour.

Comment: The test script, when run through the PHP CLI never fails. However, I thought I'd try running it via fastcgi (I just stuck it behind nginx), and I'm experiencing the same behaviour as before - fails 50% of the time.

Comment: Can you verify whether it fails once every two calls, or if it's more random? I'll probably be able to give a look at the PHP source code tomorrow.

Comment: See below for my "solution" - I'm awarding you the bounty because of the depth you went into this.

Answer (score 4):

i can show you how i am using openssl_encrypt and decrypt i am using Silex Framework and i'm not having any problems right now. I hope it helps.

I know is not the best solution but maybe can help you out

```
$encrypt_method = "aes128";
$secret_key = 'd2ae49e3b63ed418b9fc25105cd964d4';
$secret_iv = 'fb68e879fab1db2a2ce30dbf6f9b3743';
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

$output = openssl_encrypt($str, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
return base64_encode($output);


$output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($str), $encrypt_method,   $key, 0, $iv);
return $output;
```

Comment: Sorry - no dice. I copied, almost line by line, the encryption section (including the sample keys/iv) and I still get the error.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Working on a windows 10, apache xampp. php 5.6. Thats what you need?

Comment: perfect thanks. doesn't help me, but I was just wondering about overlap.

Answer (score 0):

We sort of solved this by "updating" openssl on our servers - `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` - yes, that's the exact version I listed above, I don't understand either. It's extra strange, though - because locally (on a linux VM - which I provisioned to be identical to our production environment) it worked perfectly.  I'm sorry to anyone experiencing the same problems who stumbles upon this in your darkest hour - my solution worked for me, but I don't understand any of it.